# How can I validate password and confirm password fields in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, validation, android-jetpack-compose

How can I validate user input in two fields `password` and `confirmPassword` in jetpack compose. I tried a `var matchError` but it doesn't show error when the passwords don't match. How can I fix this? Also, how can i reference the password field from `ConfirmPasswordTextFieldComponent` function? Validation occurs when the user types in the `confirmPassword` fields.

```
@Composable
fun ConfirmPasswordTextFieldComponent(
    text: String,
    labelValue: String,
    confirmText:String, painterResource: Painter,
    onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    hasError: Boolean = false,
    ) {

    val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val password = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    val passwordVisible = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val matchError = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(componentShapes.small),
        label = { Text(text = labelValue) },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Primary,
            focusedLabelColor = Primary,
            cursorColor = Primary,
            backgroundColor = BgColor
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions {
            localFocusManager.clearFocus()
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        value = password.value,
        onValueChange = {
            password.value = it
            onTextChanged(it)
        },
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(painter = painterResource, contentDescription = "")
        },
        trailingIcon = {

            val iconImage = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                Icons.Filled.Visibility
            } else {
                Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
            }

            val description = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
            } else {
                stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
            }

            IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value }) {
                Icon(imageVector = iconImage, contentDescription = description)
            }

        },
        isError = hasError || matchError.value,
        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),

    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    if (confirmText != text) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.error_password_no_match),
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorSoftRed300),
            fontSize = 10.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "ConfirmPasswordMessage" },
        )
        matchError.value = true
    } else {
        matchError.value = false
    }
}
```

PasswordTextFieldComponent:

```
@Composable
fun PasswordTextFieldComponent(
    labelValue: String, painterResource: Painter,
    onTextSelected: (String) -> Unit,
    errorStatus: Boolean = false
) {

    val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val password = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    val passwordVisible = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(componentShapes.small),
        label = { Text(text = labelValue) },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Primary,
            focusedLabelColor = Primary,
            cursorColor = Primary,
            backgroundColor = BgColor
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions {
            localFocusManager.clearFocus()
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        value = password.value,
        onValueChange = {
            password.value = it
            onTextSelected(it)
        },
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(painter = painterResource, contentDescription = "")
        },
        trailingIcon = {

            val iconImage = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                Icons.Filled.Visibility
            } else {
                Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
            }

            val description = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
            } else {
                stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
            }

            IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value }) {
                Icon(imageVector = iconImage, contentDescription = description)
            }

        },
        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        isError = !errorStatus
    )
}
```

Comment: You have to use Side Effects for validation. The state should not be changed in composable scope. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

Comment: @Abhimanyu Can you please provide how I should do that in side-effects, step wise?

Comment: Can you share more info on when you want to see the error message? I can answer accordingly. Is it on a Button Click, or as the user types on any text field or any other conditions? Please edit the question with more info.

Comment: @Abhimanyu the validation occurs as the user types in the `password` and `confirmpassword` fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified example for validation.
We can use `derivedState` for this use case.

```
@Composable
fun PasswordValidationSample() {
    var password by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var confirmPassword by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val isNotMatching = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            password != confirmPassword
        }
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(value = password, onValueChange = { password = it })
        OutlinedTextField(value = confirmPassword, onValueChange = { confirmPassword = it })
        if (isNotMatching.value) {
            Text(text = "Passwords not matching")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Abhimanu Thank you. I am still a beginner, so bear with me. But the password and confirmPassword are in different TextFieldComponents. How do I refer to password from PasswordTextFieldComponent?

Comment: If both the text fields are in different compostables, you have to hoist the state to the lowest common parent composable and add this validation logic there. Refer this for state hoisting - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting